# How can I animate a div that is vertically centered to slide-in to horizontally to the center

Tags: css

I have a modal that is vertically centered and should also be horizontally centered after sliding in, in other words, it should slide-in horizontally to the center, but only horizontally, from an already vertically centered position.

This is what I tried but it does not behaves as expected:

```css
.float-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: float-in 0.3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes float-in {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: table;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 450px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  padding: 3rem 2.5rem 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container float-in"> </div>
```

Comment: It's not CSS you posted SCSS here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) The SCSS you posted is missing a closing bracket.

2) Your `transform` properties are overwriting one another.  To have multiple transforms you must list them sequentially within the same property.  So because the element already has a Y transform, you need to include that in your animation for the X transform:

```
@keyframes float-in {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

Working demo [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/NVxLVr).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this declearation `transform: translateX(-50%);`

The revised code will be:

```
@keyframes float-in {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```